Evaluate integral $ p.v \int^{\infty}_{0} \left({p.v \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\text{Li}_n\left({\frac{y}{\sinh(y)}}\right)dy}{B^2 x^2-y^2}}\right)dx$
I need help to evaluate this integral :
$$\Omega = p.v \int^{\infty}_{0} \left({p.v \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\text{Li}_n\left({\frac{y}{\sinh(y)}}\right)dy}{B^2 x^2-y^2}}\right)dx$$
B:Constant ,$$\text{Li}_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k^n}$$
$p.v :$cauchy pricipal value
source : By : Khalef Ruhemi
In facebook

Can you explain your notation? Is $B$ a constant? What is $Li_n$? What is $p.v$?

B:Constant ,$Li_n =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k^n}$

What exactly did you try?

That’s a very strange looking integral to my eyes. I’d focus on a simple special case first like $B=n=1$ before you make the problem impossibly harder with arbitrary $n$.

I assume changing the order of integration with Fubini will help ...

Here I prove $\Omega = \frac{\pi^2}{4B}\zeta(n)$ for all $n>1$, and for $n\leq 1$ we have divergence. Assuming $B>0$, we can perform a trivial change of variables $x\mapsto x/B$ to eliminate $B$ immediately.
$$\Omega = \frac{1}{B} \text{ p.v.}\int_0^\infty \left(\text{p.v.} \int_0^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Li}_n\left(\frac{y}{\sinh(y)}\right)}{x^2-y^2} dy\right)dx$$
Ignoring $B$, this is a special case of a greatly generalizable fact. Namely, consider some function $f(t)$ which is monotonic and continuously differentiable on the interval $t\in[0,\infty)$, and where $f(t)\to 0$ in the limit of $t\to\infty$. Notice that $f(t)=\operatorname{Li}_n(y/\sinh(y))$ obeys these conditions. Given any such $f$, the following equalities hold.
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\pi^2}{4}f(0) &= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{x^2-y^2}\text{ d}y\text{ d}x \\
&= \text{ p.v.}\int_0^\infty \left(\text{p.v.} \int_0^\infty \frac{f(y)}{x^2-y^2} \text{ d}y\right)\text{ d}x
\end{align}$$
The second equality is easily proven once we notice $\text{p.v.}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2-y^2} dy=0$. Because of this, we can arbitrarily introduce the term $+\frac{C}{x^2-y^2}$ for any $C$ constant relative to $y$. By selecting $C = -f(x)$, we get the second equality described above.
To get the first equality, if $f$ is monotonic decreasing then $f(y)-f(x)\geq 0 \iff y\leq x \iff x^2-y^2 \geq 0$, with a similar phenomenon in case $f$ is monotonic increasing. Because of this we get absolute convergence, allowing us to arbitrarily rearrange parts of the integral. Relevantly, the integrand is symmetric about the line $y=x$, so we can restrict $y<x$ by introducing an extra factor of $2$. Thereafter, we can expand the denominator into a geometric series, which is again absolutely convergent.
$$\begin{align}
& \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{x^2-y^2} \text{ d}y\text{ d}x \\
&= 2\int_0^\infty \int_0^x \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{x^2-y^2} \text{ d}y\text{ d}x \\
&= 2\int_0^\infty \int_0^x (f(y)-f(x)) \frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)^j \text{ d}y\text{ d}x \\
&= 2\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \int_0^\infty x^{-2j-2}\int_0^x (f(y)-f(x))y^{2j} \text{ d}y\text{ d}x \\
&= 2\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \int_0^\infty x^{-2j-2}\left(\int_0^x f(y)y^{2j} \text{ d}y - f(x)\frac{x^{2j+1}}{2j+1}\right)\text{ d}x \\
&= 2\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \int_0^\infty x^{-2j-2}\left(\int_0^x f(y)y^{2j} \text{ d}y - \int_0^x \frac{d}{dy}f(y)\frac{y^{2j+1}}{2j+1}\text{ d}y\right)\text{ d}x \\
&= 2\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \int_0^\infty x^{-2j-2}\int_0^x \left(-f'(y)\frac{y^{2j+1}}{2j+1}\right) \text{ d}y\text{ d}x
\end{align}$$
Recall that since $f$ is monotonic, we have $f'$ either being non-negative or non-positive. In any case we once again have absolute convergence here, which enables us to swap the order of integration. This trivializes the integral on $x$, which coincidentally trivializes the integral on $y$ as well.
$$\begin{align}
&= 2\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \int_0^\infty \left(\int_y^\infty x^{-2j-2} \text{ d}x\right) \left(-f'(y)\frac{y^{2j+1}}{2j+1}\right) \text{ d}y \\
&= 2\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{y^{-2j-1}}{2j+1} \left(-f'(y)\frac{y^{2j+1}}{2j+1}\right) \text{ d}y \\
&= 2\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2j+1)^2} \int_0^\infty -f'(y) \text{ d}y \\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{4}f(0)
\end{align}$$
Miraculously, the sum and integral have separated, and we're left with two easily solvable expressions. The integral trivially evaluates to $f(0)$ due to our assumption that $f(t)\to 0$ with $t\to\infty$. Meanwhile, the sum is solved to be $\pi^2/8$, related to the Basel problem. More specifically, the sum of all reciprocal squares is $\pi^2/6$, the sum of reciprocal even squares is easily $1/4$'th of that, and the difference must be the sum of reciprocal odd squares, which is $\pi^2/8$. Anyway, going back to the original problem, and reintroducing $B$, we get the final solution as follows.
$$\begin{align}
\Omega &= \frac{\pi^2}{4B}\lim_{y\to 0}\operatorname{Li}_n\left(\frac{y}{\sinh(y)}\right) \\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{4B} \operatorname{Li}_n(1) \\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{4B}\zeta(n)
\end{align}$$
This works for all $n>1$, and for $n\leq 1$ our arguments instead prove divergence.

The differentiability of $f$ can be relaxed to local absolute continuity. The requirement $f(t)\to 0$ can also be removed, though the solution becomes $\frac{\pi^2}{4}(f(0)-f(\infty))$. Hence, the only real requirement is $f:[0,\infty) \to (-\infty,\infty)$ monotonic and locally absolutely continuous. The result is extended to $f$ with codomain $[-\infty,\infty]$ by expressing $f$ as the limit of $\max(\min(f,M),-M)$ for $M\to \infty$. That limit can be extracted from the double integral early on in my proof, and at the very end it's resolved to prove divergence in the relevant cases.

Proof given by the problem owner Prof, Khalef Ruhemi :
Take Frullani's Integral :
Let $\mathrm{a}, \mathrm{b}>0$
For every monotonic function $f$ continuously differentiable on the non - negative real numbers Suppose that both $\lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty} f(x)$ and $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} f(x)$ exists, and finite
$$
\begin{gathered}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(a x)-f(b x)}{x} d x=\left(\lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty} f(x)-\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} f(x)\right) \ln \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=A \ln \left(\frac{a}{b}\right) \\
\text { For }(a, b)=(y, 1) \text { we get : } \int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(x y)-f(x)}{x} d x=A \ln (y)
\end{gathered}
$$
Now divide both sides by $B^2-y^2$ and integrate w.r.t $y$
$$
P V \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(x y)-f(x)}{x\left(B^2-y^2\right)} d x d y=P V \int_0^{\infty} \frac{A \ln (y)}{B^2-y^2} d y
$$
Switch order of integration in the LHS :
$$
\begin{gathered}
P V \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(x y)-f(x)}{x\left(B^2-y^2\right)} d x d y=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}\left(P V \int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(x y)}{B^2-y^2} d y\right) d x-\int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}\left(P V \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d y}{B^2-y^2}\right) d x \\
P V \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d y}{B^2-y^2} \stackrel{y=B t}{=} \frac{1}{B} P V \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d t}{1-t^2}=0 \\
P V \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(x y)-f(x)}{x\left(B^2-y^2\right)} d x d y=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}\left(P V \int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(x y)}{B^2-y^2} d y\right) d x \stackrel{x y \rightarrow y}{=} \int_0^{\infty}\left(P V \int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(y)}{B^2 x^2-y^2} d y\right) d x
\end{gathered}
$$
Now we evaluate the RHS :
$$
\begin{gathered}
P V \int_0^{\infty} \frac{A \ln (y)}{B^2-y^2} d y \stackrel{y=B t}{=} \frac{A \ln B}{B} P V \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d t}{1-t^2}+\frac{A}{B} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2} d t=\frac{A}{B} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2} d t \\
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2} d t=2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2} d t=2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 t^{2 n} \ln t d t=-2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 n+1)^2}=-\frac{\pi^2}{4} \\
P V \int_0^{\infty} \frac{A \ln (y)}{B^2-y^2} d y=-\frac{A \pi^2}{4 B}
\end{gathered}
$$
Finally we get :
$$
P V \int_0^{\infty}\left(P V \int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(y)}{B^2 x^2-y^2} d y\right) d x=\frac{\pi^2}{4 B}\left(\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} f(x)-\lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty} f(x)\right) \quad(B>0)
$$
Application : for $f(y)=\operatorname{Li}_n\left(\frac{y}{\sinh y}\right) \quad \lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty} f(x)=0 ; f(0)=\operatorname{Li}_n(1)=\zeta(n)(n>1)$
$$
P V \int_0^{\infty}\left(P V \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{Li}_n\left(\frac{y}{\sinh y}\right)}{B^2 x^2-y^2} d y\right) d x=\frac{\pi^2}{4 B} \zeta(n) \quad(n>1 ; B>0)
$$

Wow... really nice generalization and application. Thanks for sharing (+1)
